# CLLocationManager, Core Data and Arrays

Tags: swift, core-data, mapkit, core-location, cllocationmanager

I've got this function and am so close to making it work! I think I am having a conversion issue. I can get the coordinates into an Entity with 3 Attributes lat (Double), long (Double) and time (Date). That works and I can print the contents to the screen, and it looks good. But when I try and extract and use as coordinates on the map, it doesn't work. I think this is because they are not being recognized as true coordinates. Any ideas?

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        //ARRAY for lat/long data
        var latArr:[Double] = []
        var longArr:[Double] = []
        var timeArr:[Date] = []

        let location = locations[0]
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
        let myLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
        //annotation.coordinate = myLocation
        //annotation.title = "\(location.timestamp)"
        //self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.mapView.showsUserLocation = false //SET THIS
        latitude.text = "latitude: " + "\(location.coordinate.latitude)"
        longitude.text = "longitude: " + "\(location.coordinate.longitude)"
        altitude.text = "altitude: " + "\(location.altitude)"
        speed.text = "speed: " + "\(location.speed)"
        timestamp.text = "timestamp: " + "\(location.timestamp)"

        //START -- Core Data
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Data")
        request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        let data = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Data", into: context)
        //let data = NSNumber(double: self.location?.coordinate.latitude)

        let dlat = Double("\(location.coordinate.latitude)")
        let dlong = Double("\(location.coordinate.longitude)")

        data.setValue(dlat, forKey: "lat")
        data.setValue(dlong, forKey: "long")
        data.setValue(location.timestamp, forKey: "time")
        //END -- Core Data

        do
        {
            try context.save()
            //print("Saved")
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        do
        {
            var lat: Double = 0
            var long: Double = 0
            let t = NSDate()
            let results = try context.fetch(request)

            if results.count > 0
            {
                for result in results as! [NSManagedObject]
                {
                    if let datalat = result.value(forKey: "lat") as? Double
                    {
                        //latArr.append(datalat)
                        let lat = datalat
                        print(lat)
                    }
                    if let datalong = result.value(forKey: "long") as? Double
                    {
                        //longArr.append(datalong)
                        let long = datalong
                        print(long)
                    }
                    if let time = result.value(forKey: "time") as? Date
                    {
                        //timeArr.append(time)
                        let t = time
                        print(t)
                    }
                    let mLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, long)
                    annotation.coordinate = mLocation
                    annotation.title = "\(t)"
                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {

        }
```

Comment: "It doesn't work" in what specific way?

Comment: Never ever have an empty catch{} statement. At the very least put a log statement in it. Errors might be flying, but you'll never know about them now, won't you?

Comment: Are you sure you're showing the right area of the map?  To be safe, you could add   mapView.showAnnotation(annotation, animated: false)

Answer (score 1):

I compared your code to a function that I'm using in a similar scenario and incorporated any differences (and did a bit of editing for brevity that you can take or leave).  The relevant section follows:

```
    let request = NSFetchRequest<Data>(entityName: "Data")
let annotations: [MKAnnotation] = []

annotation.title = “\(t)”

for result in results  
{
    if data.lat != nil && data.lon != nil
    {
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: data.lat.doubleValue, longitude: data.lon.doubleValue)
        annotations.append(annotation)
    }
    self.mapView.addAnnotations(annotations)
    self.mapView.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: false)
}
```

My code works, but it is Swift 3.0 so some differences may be due to the changes from earlier versions if you're using 2.2.or 2.3.  I know that I needed to push it from NSNumber (from CoreData) to a Double, but I think you'd get a compile error if that were the issue - not sure why you're not.  As mentioned in my comment, the show Annotation will help if the waypoints are simply outside the visible map area.

Other than that, your code looks OK to me - let me know if it's still acting up.

Comment: thank you. I am getting this error: Value of type 'NSManagedObject' has no member 'lat'. Any ideas? And this error: Value of type 'MKMapView' has no member 'showAnnotation'

Comment: I changed the fetch request to tie it to your Data entity (not an ideal name BTW...) and realized that the showAnnotations has to be plural - so I changed the flow to use an array, which is how my flow goes anyway.

Comment: still hung up. where does data.lat come from? also, thank you for all of your help

Comment: You're welcome... Sorry, from the above it was my understanding that your entity 'Data' has fields called 'lat' and 'lon', which the suggested code tests against and then uses to calculate the CLLocation.  What's happening?